# How to create folder inside photos library in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, phphotolibrary

I am working on a photo sharing app in iOS. It creates a lot of albums in the photos library. But I want to have a single folder in device photos library and have all my albums inside of it. I know how to create an album in photos library and also that we cannot create album inside of an album. I have searched everywhere but I cannot find anything. Any help would be appreciated.